# CUDA matrix preferred indexing method

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

Let's say that I have a 4x4 matrix, which is divided into 2x2 block and 2x2 grid, so `func<<<(2,2), (2,2)>>>()`. The matrix is stored in a 1d array of size 16. The usual method to calculate `x` and `y` is the following:

```
int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

It seems like the recommended (at least by multiple examples) way to calculate the global index is:

```
int index = y * width + x;
```

This would generate the following indices:

```
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 0, threadIdx.x = 0, index = 0
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 0, threadIdx.x = 1, index = 1
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 1, threadIdx.x = 0, index = 4
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 1, threadIdx.x = 1, index = 5
```

So, on each `y` increment, the index would be strided, which means that only the `x` threads would benefit from coalescing. Another way to calculate the index is:

```
int index = y * blockDim.x + x;
```

Which would give the following indices:

```
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 0, threadIdx.x = 0, index = 0
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 0, threadIdx.x = 1, index = 1
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 1, threadIdx.x = 0, index = 2
blockIdx.x,y = 0, threadIdx.y = 1, threadIdx.x = 1, index = 3
```

In this case, the entire block is coalesced as all threads would access consecutive elements of the array.

Why is the first method generally recommended? Doesn't the second one achieve a better performance?

Comment: Note that the ```y * width + x``` could also be to work with padded matrices, such as those created by ```cudaMalloc3D```, or matrix slices. Matrix width and stride independent from block dimensions is pretty common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the first method generally recommended?

One possibility might be that no one really thinks problems involving a 4x4 matrix accessed across a 4x4 grid are useful to tune for.  Once you get to large matrices broken into 32x32 tiles, this becomes moot. (&)

> Another way to calculate the index is:

```
int index = y * blockDim.x + x;
```

I don't think so.  One thread in your grid will have an `(x,y)` ordered pair of `(0,1)`.  Another will have an ordered pair of `(2,0)`. Considering your proposed value for `blockDim.x` of 2, those two threads will yield the same `index` value.  I don't imagine that is what you want.

(&) And with no loss of generality in my opinion, if I wanted to create threadblocks of less than 32x32 = 1024 threads, I would scale down the block y dimension, e.g. 32x16 for 512 threads, or 32x8 for 256 threads.  This allows me to use the same indexing "everywhere".